# i am trying to create a simple jqgrid in jsp page, all code seems good but the grid is not showing up below is the code

Tags: jquery, jsp

i am trying to create a simple jqgrid in jsp page, all code seems good but the grid is not showing up below is the code

i am new to this jqgrid plugin and jquery, i dont know whats wrong in this i tried all possible ways , but i am not getting any output

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
var myData = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "aaz"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "bbz"
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "ccz"
}, ];

$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ["Id", "Name"],
    colModel: [{
        name: "id",
        index: "id",
        sorttype: "int"
    }, {
        name: "name",
        index: "name"
    }],
    caption: "Viz Test",
    pager: '#pager',
    search: true,
    multiselect: true,
    data: myData
});
</script>

</head>


<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
<table id="list47"></table>
<div id="plist47"></div>
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
var myData = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "aaz"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "bbz"
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "ccz"
}, ];

$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ["Id", "Name"],
    colModel: [{
        name: "id",
        index: "id",
        sorttype: "int"
    }, {
        name: "name",
        index: "name"
    }],
    caption: "Viz Test",
    pager: '#pager',
    search: true,
    multiselect: true,
    data: myData
});
</script>
```

just above

Like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.7/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/themes/ui.jqgrid.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>




</head>


<body>
<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
<table id="list47"></table>
<div id="plist47"></div>
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>


 <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
var myData = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "aaz"
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: "bbz"
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: "ccz"
}, ];

$("#list").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    colNames: ["Id", "Name"],
    colModel: [{
        name: "id",
        index: "id",
        sorttype: "int"
    }, {
        name: "name",
        index: "name"
    }],
    caption: "Viz Test",
    pager: '#pager',
    search: true,
    multiselect: true,
    data: myData
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```